# how can i check if a local account has a password enabled?

Tags: linux

i need to make a script that checks whether a local account either has password enabled or simply a blank password. i'm guessing they're the same thing yeah?

i googled around and tried the password -S user command, but all i got is an error. do i have to run that on local terminal console or is there a way to turn that into a script?

im super new so im still a bit confused with the concept of script in general. basically i have to write the script in one of the text editor, save it as .sh file, give it RWX permission, then run it through terminal, correct?

Comment: In either case the account has a password, a blank password, is a password to Windows.

Comment: What is the exact error when you try `password -S user`? Do you mean `passwd -S user`? Please avoid asking multiple questions in one post. Let this question be about passwords. If you need help with script creation in general, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

The password of a user is store in the `/etc/shadow` file. The file consists of `:`-seperated fields. The second field is the password. If a password is set, a hash is shown. If an account is disabled or has no password it will either show a `!` or nothing.

You could use a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="$1"
passwordField=$(cat /etc/shadow | grep "$1" | cut -d ':' -f 2)

echo "Password field contains: ${passwordField}"

if [[ "${passwordField}x" == "x" || "$passwordField" == '!' ]]; then
  echo "Password is not set or account is disabled"
else
  echo "Password is set"
fi
```

Store this text in a file. Make the file executable with `chmod +x filename` and run the file as root user with the username as argument:

```
root@frisbee:~# ./checkpw.sh test1
Password field contains: $6$WLmjys98$70x/mzE/syE4CGgK9GvcN0Bz1b9.6Ka.JsZQ7W9OFwvTx17MKtQegQKVweaRl5M3X.Wm/EDdBOEEfdalDR225/
Password is set
root@frisbee:~# passwd -d test1
passwd: password expiry information changed.
root@frisbee:~# ./checkpw.sh test1
Password field contains: 
Password is not set or account is disabled
```

*This simple script does have the limitation that if the argument provided is part of two or more usernames, it will not have reliable output.*